# get file path as string in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'd like to be able to get the file path of a link in emacs org-mode as a string, which I could then parse in various ways and return to `org-open-file`. So, e.g., the link `[[file:/path/to/file.org]][link text]` would return the string `/path/to/file.org`. I'm betting this is basic elisp, but I'm new to elisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this information from the [Org element API](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html).  Here
is an example that gets the path and opens it in a Dired buffer.

```
(defun km/org-link-dired-jump ()
  "Open Dired for directory of file link at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((el (org-element-lineage (org-element-context) '(link) t)))
    (unless (and el (equal (org-element-property :type el) "file"))
      (user-error "Not on file link"))
    (dired-jump 'other-window
                (expand-file-name (org-element-property :path el)))))
```

(This depends on Org version 8.3 or greater.)